# How to determine the files in projects which does not have tests added

Tags: dart, github, testing, github-actions, test-coverage

I'm Maintaining a repo for Dart. All files are independent files with separate main functions. I need to figure out the files which don't have tests. The only way I can think of is manually. I would like to know if we can list out files which don't have tests in the GitHub actions.